# String of filenames

Tags: java

Can someone please help me on this task, I appreciate your taking time.

There are huge number of filenames(String of filenames) and I have to get the ID form each file name from the below sample filenames.

```
1100_007_1_ALL_GC_Identify_TOA.txt
1100_007_2_ALL_GC_Identify_TOA.txt
1100_008A_1_ALL_GC_Set_Individual_In-Active.txt
1100_008B_2_ALL_GC_Set_Individual_In-Active_TP.txt
1100_001_TOA_Indiv.txt
1100_002_TOA_Indiv.txt
1100_006_ALL_GC_Check_In_Active_TOA.txt
1100_010_TOA_Control_1.txt

Final output should be :-
File ID's:
1100_007_1
1100_007_2
1100_008A_1
1100_008B_1
1100_001
1100_002
1100_006
1100_010
```

I tried the following but it does not work for file 1100_008A_1

```
public static String stripNonDigits(final String input){
   final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++){
      final char c = input.charAt(i);
      if(c > 47 && c < 58){
         sb.append(c);
      }
   }
   return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything, or are you just looking for a small amount of free programming?

Comment: We can help fix your code but we won't write it for you.

Comment: Just check if your `char == '_'` and the following one is a letter. If so, substring it with the last _.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the examples given by you, this would work:

```
String filename = "1100_007_1_ALL_GC_Identify_TOA.txt";
String id = filename.replaceAll("_\\D.*", "");
```

The following regular expression assumes that right after 'ID' part there is a '_' sign followed by some character other than digit.

Comment: that will be fine unless those are hex numbers, in which case he could have a hex number 'digit' (a-f) in any position.  But for the examples given, and possibly for everything he has, this looks fine.  I was about to suggest terminating before the underscore before the first grouping of non-underscore that contained any letter that was not a hex digit.